# Dynamic Audit Trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to keep logs of all tables into 1 single log table. Suppose if any DML operation is going on any table inside DB. Than that should be logged in 1 single tables.

**But there should be a dynamic trigger which will not hard coded the column names for every table.**

Is there any solution for this.

Regards,

Somdutt Harihar

Answer (score 3):

> "Is there any solution for this"

No. This is not how databases work. Strongly enforced data structures is what they do, and that applies to audit tables just as much as transaction tables.

The reason is quite clear: the time you save not writing audit code specific to each transactional table is the time you will spend writing a query to retrieve the audit records. The difference is, when you're trying to get the audit records out you will have your boss standing over your shoulder demanding to know when you can tell them what happened to the payroll records last month. Or asking how long it will take you to produce that report for the regulators, are you trying to make the company look like a bunch of clowns? You get the picture. This is not where you want to be.

Also, the performance of a single table to store all the changes to all the tables in the database? That is going to be so slow, you have no idea.

The point is, we can generate the auditing code. It is easy to write some SQL which interrogates [the data dictionary](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_2102.htm#REFRN20276) and produces DDL for the target tables and triggers to populate those tables.

In fact it gets even easier in 11.2.0.4 and later because we can use FLASHBACK DATA ARCHIVE (formerly Oracle Total Recall) to build and maintain such journalling functionality automatically, and query it automatically with the `as of` syntax. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS01011).

---

Okay, so technically there is a solution. You could have a trigger on each table which executes some dynamic PL/SQL to interrogate the data dictionary and assembles a piece of JSON which you stuff into your single table. The single table could be partitioned by day range and sub-partitioned by table name (assuming you have licensed the Partitioning option) to mitigate the performance of querying it.

But that is extremely complex. Running dynamic PL/SQL for every DML statement will have a bad effect on performance, which the users will notice. And this still doesn't solve the fundamental problem of retrieving the audit trail when you need it.

Comment: Thanks for the help APC. This is helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

To audit DML actions on any table just enable such audit by using following code:

```
audit insert table, update table, delete table;
```

All actions with tables will then be logged to **sys.dba_audit_object** table.

Audit will only log timestamp, user, host and other params, not exact copies of new or old rows.